Spring security authentication failure triggering a login dialog with 401 unauthorised
I am using Spring Boot 3.2.5 with Spring Security 6 for my project. The authentication mechanism I have implemented is based on username and password, and I am using JWT (JSON Web Tokens) for authenticating REST API requests. For data storage, I have chosen MongoDB as the backend.
I have created a custom login page for user authentication. However, when authentication fails due to an incorrect username, instead of displaying an appropriate error message on the login page, I am getting a pop-up dialog box.
I would like to modify the authentication flow to display the error message directly on the login page itself, rather than showing a pop-up dialog box.
**My SecurityConfig **
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableReactiveMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.SecurityWebFiltersOrder;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordencoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity serverHttpSecurity, AuthConverter authConverter, AuthManager authManager){


        AuthenticationWebFilter jwtRequestFilter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(authManager);
        jwtRequestFilter.setServerAuthenticationConverter(authConverter);

        serverHttpSecurity
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
                        .pathMatchers("/authenticate", "/get_validation", "/post_transactions", "/css/**",
                                "/images/**", "/js/**").permitAll()
                        .pathMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                        .anyExchange().authenticated()
                ).addFilterAt(jwtRequestFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                .httpBasic(ServerHttpSecurity.HttpBasicSpec::disable)
                .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
                .formLogin(ServerHttpSecurity.FormLoginSpec::disable);


        return serverHttpSecurity.build();
    }

}



Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, this ist not a How To site where you can ask for implementations based on your specific requirements. I'd suggest to start with Spring Tutorials to get some first impressions, and maybe follow up with dedicated tutorials on YouTube or Udemy or something else.
